# Adding an item to the end of a multi-column listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

Being a beginner in this, I've tried to search for a solution to my issue. I created a form in Access 2013 with a `List Box`. The `List Box` is **bounded** to a table with 10 fields.

For the `List Box`, in the Property Sheet, I've set the `Column Count` to **10**, but have hidden some columns, i.e. some has a `Column Widths` of **0"** because I'm only showing important data in the `List Box`.

The `Row Source Type` of the `List Box` is set to **Table/Query**.

When I open the form, it queries the table and populates the `List Box` with all data.

I have 4 **unbounded** `Text Box` that allows the user to enter data, and have a button to allow the input data to be added to the end of the `List Box` and also be automatically added to the table.

I've searched for how to do this:

1. [Add items to a multi-column List Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399692/add-items-to-a-multi-column-list-box)
2. [vba listbox multicolumn add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213962/vba-listbox-multicolumn-add)
3. [Adding items in a Listbox with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973287/adding-items-in-a-listbox-with-multiple-columns)
4. [Adding values multiple columns to listbox in form access vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870600/adding-values-multiple-columns-to-listbox-in-form-access-vba)
5. [Excel multi-select, multi-column listboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273460/excel-multi-select-multi-column-listboxes)

I've tried to use the `.List` property of the `List Box`, but it does not exist.

I've tried to do something like:

```
Me.MyList.AddItem "" & ";" & Me.textBoxValueOne & ";" & Me.testBoxValueTwo & ";" & ""
```

However, VBA complains I need to change the `.RowSourceType` to **Value List**, and when I added it, the `List Box` clears all the data, and adds this data as the first entry, which is not what I want.

I've added the following code, which adds a blank entry to the end of the `List Box` as well as table, but I don't know where to go further with it to save the input data from the `Text Box` to the end of the `List Box` and table:

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
Me.MyList.Requery
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the record to the table first and then requery your listbox.

After adding the new record try

```
Me![column name] = textbox1.value
And other textboxes
Followed by your save command.
```

Once you've added the record. Simply requery the listbox.

```
Me.listbox.requery
```